# Linking to a link with and ID and reposistion

Tags: javascript, html, css

On this page - http://binkley2.nowmgbeta.com/services - I'm using id tags so that I can link to those section using my drop down menu. My Sticky header is giving me issues though. Is there a way to have the positioning change when I go to that link? I'm wanting to be able to see the heading title when you click one of the drop down menu links.

```
<h2 id="Lot-Splits">Lot Splits / Consolidation Surveys</h2>
```

Comment: Please add the relevant code to your post.

Comment: You will probably get downvoted because you're asking people to debug your site, rather than asking a question which can benefit others as well.

Comment: Thank you for you help. I will add the code. I posted this because I'm sure someone else will have this same issue:)

Answer (score 1):

You could run this on page load

```
if(window.location.hash.length){
     $(window).scrollTop($(window).scrollTop() - 100);
}
```

Comment: I added this code to the header put it is not working. Can you have a look and see why it's not working? http://binkley2.nowmgbeta.com/services/#Lot-Splits

Comment: You need to include jquery for this code to work, I assumed you were using it.
Add this to your header before the script tag with the code I posted <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>